# jasper report is not printing properly

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i am printing  using jasper report , i created report using ireport plugin of netbeans,
so when i see the pre view is looks fine , but when i am printing the data its not well formatted only header band is coming in print page following is my code

```
     void showResports(){
    try{
      // OriginalExportOriginalExport 
         String reportName ="";
        //ExportReport4.jasperExportReport4.jasper
        if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
  reportName = "src/reports/OriginalExport.jasper";
        }
        else if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
         reportName = "src/reports/ExportReport4.jasper";
 
        }
//  InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
  InputStream in=new FileInputStream(reportName);
  
  if(in==null|| connection==null) return ;
  JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, null, connection);
  System.out.println("Object of Jasper Print created");
 
  
              JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);
 
     //Insert viewer to a JFrame to make it showable
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
            jf.validate();
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
            jf.setLocation(300,100);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                /*
   * 
   * 
  File f=new File(reportName);
  if(f.exists()) System.out.println("Yes Yes File is there");
  else 
  System.out.println("File is not there"+f.getAbsolutePath());
   */
  
   }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();}
    
    }// showReports

}
```

please help i am so worried

Edit:
I am viewing the file in JRViewer then simly printing it , also when i save as from ireport netbean plugin into pdf also only header come there i dont know what is the issue,

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the size of Jframe. Also try to first export your report as file (using any of the JRExporter implementation) to see if the generated report looks fine.

Comment: There are two reports here, You checked the preview for both the reports OriginalExport.jasper and ExportReport4.jasper ? Just wanted to make sure you checking the correct report. Or in both the reports just the header is coming

Comment: both has header , now see another thing  , just printed the report by ireport it works well , is there any issues with JRViewer?